# Android Programming SQL PHP

Tags: java, php, android, sql

I am working on android application where it uploads store information (Such as Store_Name, Store_Address & Store_PhoneNumber)from the application i have written the PHP code which works fine but when i see in the database, data is not being uploaded there....I want data to be uploaded in the database and be shown in the database

I am hosting this with the help of hostinger....

PHP File:-

```
<?php
    define('HOST','mysql.hostinger.in');
    define('USER','u400625220_user');
    define('PASS','1234567890');
    define('DB','u400625220_medi');     
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
    $SName = $_GET['SName'];
    $SAdd = $_GET['SAdd'];
    $SNum = $_GET['SNum'];
            if($SName == '' || $SAdd == '' || $SNum == '')
            {
            echo 'please fill all values';
            }
            else
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM StoreRegister WHERE Store_Name = '$SName' OR Store_Address = '$SAdd' OR Store_PhoneNo = '$SNum'";
                $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysql_query($con,$sql));
                if(isset($check))
                {
                    echo 'StoreName or Address or Phone Number already Exist'; 
                }
                else
                {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO StoreRegister (Store_Name,Store_Address,Store_PhoneNo) VALUES('$SName','$SAdd','$SNum')";
                    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
                    {
                        echo 'successfully registered';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Please try again!'
                    }
                }
                mysqli_close($con)
            }?>
```

Java Code:-

```
public class StoreSignUp extends AppCompatActivity{
EditText edit_Storename;
EditText edit_Storeadd;
EditText edit_Storephone;
Button btn_register;

private static final String Reg_URL = "http://popgmail.esy.es/MediStore/StoreCon.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_sign_up);
    edit_Storename = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_Sname);
    edit_Storeadd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_Sadd);
    edit_Storephone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_Sphone);

    btn_register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);
    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerStore();
        }
    });

}

private void registerStore(){
    String storename = edit_Storename.getText().toString();
    String storeadd = edit_Storeadd.getText().toString();
    String storephone = edit_Storephone.getText().toString();
    register(storename, storeadd, storephone);
}

private void register(String Sname,String Sphone, String Sadd){
    String urlSuffix = "?StoreName="+Sname+"&PhoneNumber="+Sphone+"&Address="+Sadd;
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(StoreSignUp.this,"Please Wait",null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(Reg_URL+s);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result;
                result = br.readLine();
                return result;

            }catch (Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    RegisterUser ur = new RegisterUser();
    ur.execute(urlSuffix);

}
```

}

My Database name is StoreRegister.
I am just a beginner and starting with this application as my first android project if any mistakes do tell me so that it can be helpful to me in the future..
Hope a Good And Easy Solution!!!Thank You!!!

Comment: ALWAYS run PHP with enabled Error reporting while developing! See how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: I have refered it but not so familiar about the usage of the code if possible can u just explain me in easier way....!!!

Comment: I have refered it but not so familiar about the usage of the code if possible can u just explain me in easier way....!!! I think there is no error in the code but can u just give me an idea or the solution for the problem which i have mentioned...

Comment: Add the code mentioned in [](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/1456401) `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);` just after php opening tag `<?php `. If there is any error it should be printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'Please try again!'
mysqli_close($con)
```

Two lines have to end with ';'.

And your parameter is wrong.

Your PHP Source is

```
$SName = $_GET['SName'];
$SAdd = $_GET['SAdd'];
$SNum = $_GET['SNum'];
```

And your Android request url is

```
String urlSuffix = "?StoreName="+Sname+"&PhoneNumber="+Sphone+"&Address="+Sadd;
```

Change it as following:

```
String urlSuffix = "?SName="+Sname+"&SAdd="+Sphone+"&SNum="+Sadd;
```

Comment: @Aakash My pleasure, If worked well, confirm my answer and end your question. Thank you.